# Asking mex to use several directories for #include files

Tags: matlab

I read in the documentation for MATLAB's mex [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mex.html) the following:

> **-Ipathname** : Add pathname to the list of folders to search for **#include**
>   files. Do not add a space after this switch.

How can I ask mex to use *multiple* include folders? Do I provide them as
-Ipath1 -Ipath2 etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes; for example:

```
mex -Iinclude/path/one -Iinclude/path/two -I"include/path/with spaces" mymexfile.c
```